# Changing renewable subscription in iOS In-app purchase triggers "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" error

Tags: ios, react-native, in-app-purchase

I have multiple renewable subscriptions set up for my App in App Store Connect.

[image]

There are a handful of renewable subscriptions which are all part of the same subscription group, plus one which is a non-renewable subscription.

I am using `react-native-iap` which uses the StoreKit under the hood.

I am using a sandox user account as created under "Users and Access" > "Sandbox" > "Testers" logged in as a sandbox user on the iPhone. I am logged in as that user on the iPhone under "iTunes & App Stores" > "SANDBOX ACCOUNT".

I can successfully fetch the subscriptions using 'RNIap.getSubscriptions()' and display them in the UI. I can then successfully trigger a purchase of a subscription using `RNIap.requestSubscription(productId, false)` after which my registered `RNIap.purchaseUpdatedListener` handler correctly fires, and I finish the transaction using `RNIap.finishTransactionIOS(purchase.transactionId)`. So far, so good.

The problem arises when I try to make subsequent changes to the renewable subscription, by following the same process with one of the other subscriptions. I get a pop-up asking whether I want to confirm the modification to the new subscription, as expected, followed by "You're all set, Your purchase was successful". But I when this happens it actually calls the `RNIap.purchaseErrorListener` event handler, rather than the `RNIap.purchaseUpdatedListener` as expected.

The error message I get from the handler is:

```
{
    responseCode: "0",
    code: "E_UNKNOWN",
    debugMessage: "Cannot connect to iTunes Store",
    message: "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"
}
```

Which originates from the `StoreKit` api itself when `transaction.transactionState` is equal to `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed`.

If I then ettempt to buy thnon-renewable subscription (1 Week in the above example) the purchase is successful, triggering the `RNIap.purchaseUpdatedListener` as expected. But whenever I try to change the subscription to another renewable subscription again the `RNIap.purchaseErrorListener` handler is triggered.

So I guess my question is this: "Why does the `RNIap.purchaseErrorListener` handler trigger instead of the `RNIap.purchaseUpdatedListener` handler when trying to change from a renewable subscription to another renewable subscription?"

Comment: Are you testing on a physical device or emulator? We've seen some weird behavior with the new iOS Simulators so it's worth testing on a physical device as well.

Comment: @enc_life yeah it's on a physical device - iPhone 6s